# Maximality of an ideal for showing that an algebra is in fact a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have an algebra $A$ over the field $F$, with the finite dimensionality $n$ as a vector space over $F$. I can also assume that $A$ is an integral domain. Assuming that $v_1,...,v_n$ is a spanning list of vectors and that $v_1=1$, I believe I can represent $A$ as
$F[v_1,v_2,...,v_n]/I$ where $$I=\left(v_1-1,\ v_iv_j\ \forall\ 2\leq i,j\leq n\right).$$
Now, I'd hope to show that $A$ is a field by proving the maximality of $I$, but I can't figure out how to show that.

Comment: What is $R$?  Your question doesn't define it.  Cheers!

Comment: The factor ring as it is defined is not integral $v_iv_j=0$ but $v_i\neq0$ and $v_j\neq0$.

Comment: Thanks @mouthetics, I see that now. I must have misinterpreted what the lecturer was saying. I'll ask a separate question to try and clarify.

Comment: Probably you won't like this. Let $0\neq \alpha\in A$ then $F[\alpha]$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $A$ over $F$. So there is $n\geq 1$ such that $\{1,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^n\}$ is linearly dependent. $\textit{i.e.}$ there is $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$ not all zero such that $a_0+a_1\alpha+\cdots+a_n\alpha^n=0$. Let $0\leq i<n$ be the smallest $i$ such that $a_i\neq 0$. Then $a_i\alpha^i+\cdots+a_n\alpha^n=0\Rightarrow 1+{a_{i+1}\over a_i}\alpha+\cdots+{a_n\over a_i}\alpha^{n-i}=0$. From this you get that $\alpha$ is invertible.

Comment: @mouthetics that's definitely another cool way to go about the problem thank you. I do have one question about it. How do we know there will always the powers $\{1,\alpha,...,\alpha^n\}$ will be distinct for enough n? For example, there will often be elements with multiplicative order 2, or for example in $\mathbb{F_(5^4)}$ there are two elements with order 3 (which I think would still not be enough to necessarily be linearly dependent). How does the argument hold for when $\alpha$ has low multiplicative order like in these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a different way to show $A$ is a field. We will simply show that if $a\in A$ is nonzero, then $a$ has a multiplicative inverse in $A$. Consider the $F$-linear map $M_a:A\to A$ given by $M_a(b) = a\cdot b$. It is an injective $F$-linear map between $F$-vector spaces of the same (finite) dimension, and so it is also surjective. Therefore, $M_a(b) = 1$ for some $b\in A$, i.e., $a\cdot b = 1$.